# How to keep changes made on sqlite database

Tags: django, database, sqlite, heroku

I have a Django app with a `SQLite` database. This app is deployed on Heroku.

When someone uses the app and add data into the database, the sqlite database is modified. But when I make a code change on Github and then deploy this new version of my app, I also deploy the sqlite database (which doesn't have the new changes made by the users) and so I remove the changes.

What is the best process to prevent this ?

Comment: 1. don't include the sqlite file in your repository. 2. do a dumpdata of your up to date db before you pull new code.  then loaddata after you update your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple: you must not use sqlite on Heroku. As you have discovered, the file system on Heroku is ephemeral, and changes aren't persisted between deploys. Plus, if you scaled to more than one dyno, they wouldn't share the same database.

Use the Postgres add-on instead.

Comment: I (am trying to) use SQLite on Heroku just to record states for a worker script. Heroku seems to delete the sqlite file. Then I created a backup (+recover) and appended it with  ".backup" and those are also getting erased form instance.  I do see them when running the process, but they still "go away".  I am playing with a few more hacks before I give up.  I like SQlite as I am running like an embedded device and using the db for tracking worker info only related to the 10-40seconds it is alive.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying this. As my answer to this question indicated, the file system is ephemeral and not shared between dynos. Each script invocation is a new dyno. This cannot work.

Comment: I know. In my need SQLite exists only for the new dyno to track details of the worker operation so it can report back. My comment is just a note on failures to try and help others and/or spark a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Heroku but if there's a seperate copy of your databse files on Heroku then you should add your sqlite files to the .gitignore file. This way you sqlite files won't be sent to Heroku along with the rest of the code. Also you'll need to delete the sqlite files from your repo which have already been added. Search more about gitignore. A general .gitignore for Django projects contains the following -

```
*.pyc
__pycache__
myvenv
db.sqlite3
.DS_Store
settings.py
```

Just copy this to your existing gitignore or make a new if not already present. A gigignore file is usually present in the root directory of the project.

Comment: Yes I thought about this but then I don't have any backup/history of my database... Does it matter ?

Comment: If you want to backup db, make a copy of it before you commit, and commit the copy.  Exclude the current db with .gitignore as @jyotmansingh