# Django problem - server deployed on Heroku, everytime I login and I don't spend time on website I can't login with same credentials

Tags: django, authentication, heroku, heroku-cli

Two years ago I have programmed a Django website and I deployed on Heroku. As I remember in that times if i was automatically logged out I could log in with no problems.
Now I have started to work on this website in the testing side, a project from my dissertation thesis and everytime I am logging in and if my computer goes sleep mode or I don't click my website for a brief amount of time I can't login back with the same credentials.
Have you encountered the same problem? I don't know what to do.

Comment: What does "can't log back in with the same credentials" mean? What do you do instead?

Comment: I have to create a new user everytime. The same credentials mean the credentials I used for the last user created in app.

Comment: Wild guess: are you using SQLite as your database?

Comment: Your wild guess is right..

Comment: That won't work. See [How to keep changes made on sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35113743/354577), [Heroku: Django database file lost on every dyno restart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42742956/354577), [Prevent Django SQLite db from being overwritten while pushing to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23738598/354577)